# RESOLVIDO - Como ler este JSON em PHP

Tags: php, json

Senhores, estou recebendo o JSON via URL e tento recuperar os valores via PHP, mas sempre esta me retornando o erro:

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exames\adm\testes.php on line 25

PHP

```
$jsonTeste = '{"exames": [
{
            "nomeExame": "",
            "descricaoExame": "",
            "valorExame": 0.00,},{
            "nomeExame": "MAPA - 24 HORAS",
            "descricaoExame": "",
            "valorExame": 80.00,},{
            "nomeExame": "HOLTER - 24 HORAS",
            "descricaoExame": "",
            "valorExame": 80.00,}],
    "sucesso": "true",
    "mensagemErro": "Requisição efetuada com sucesso"
  }';

  $json = json_decode($jsonTeste, TRUE);
   foreach($json as $row ){
    echo $row->nomeExame;
   }
```

**RESOLVIDO**
Estava recebendo o JSON com erros, com o ***preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $conteudo);*** consegui solucionar, ficando assim:

```
$conteudo = file_get_contents('minha_url');
$result = json_decode($conteudo);
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $conteudo);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tbody>"; 
foreach($json["exames"] as $exame){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $exame["nomeExame"] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><small>" . $exame["descricaoExame"] . '</small></td>';
      echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody>";
echo "<table>";
```

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128670/discussion-on-question-by-cristiano-facirolli-como-ler-este-json-em-php) - Quem quiser acompanhar ou acrescentar algo pode utilizar o link fornecido.